# Symfony2 Ajax Login with popup Form

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, authentication

I'm new to Symfony2, i've made a form login which works well, but i would like to have an ajax popup login form, with such when the user tries to go to a page that needs to be authenticated, a login form pops up, after login the user will just be able to access authorized functions on that page. i followed the [instructions on this page](http://www.webtipblog.com/adding-an-ajax-login-form-to-a-symfony-project/), it still redirects to my original login form page.

Here's my app/config/security.yml

```
    firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous:  ~
        http_basic:
            realm:  "Secured Admin Area"
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /index
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path:  login_check
            default_target_path: /index
            success_handler: authentication_handler
            failure_handler: authentication_handler
```

The success_handler and failer_handler are added for Ajax login. It just not work as what i expected, can anyone give me some hints or link to a good tutorial? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false

    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous:  ~
        http_basic:
            realm:  "Secured Admin Area"
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /index
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path:  login_check
            default_target_path: /index
            success_handler: authentication_handler
            failure_handler: authentication_handler
```